# Windows running an executable from a network path

Tags: windows, networking

When you run an executable that resides on a network path relative to the machine you are using, for example, `\\networkmachine\folder\target.exe arg1 arg2`, I know that it is executed locally, but does anyone know if the command line arguments end up getting passed across the network connection?

Comment: Well, the best would be to test it with a simple exe, but I don't see why it would be blocked anyway...

Comment: The command line arguments are passed to the executable instance running locally. Simple as that.

Comment: I've never considered it.  The process is built locally, there is no need to send any such data to the remote filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse not. Start thinking on the lines how your binary which sits in network location gets executed in local machine. When you execute the command, the immideate task which is responsible for command execution (in Linux shell, in windows I don't know what) take whole command you typed in as its argument parse it to understand that it is an instruction to execute an executable and the first argument is the name of the executable the next arguments are the arguments to be passed to it. Then it tries to start the execution, in Linux it does `fork()` and then `exec()`. Basically, try to load the executable on memory and then keeps the arguments in place before start of execution. To load the executable to memory, it has to read the executable and this is the time it will try to read the executable file, and this is exactly the time it will do the network operation (in your case) or disk read operation if it is in disk. If it is in Linux, and NFS sort of network hosted file, network operation will again go down one more layer as the loader does a regular file read and the NFS layer does the necessary network operation to make the data available. There is no point in this sequence where you have to send the arguments through network.

So, to sum it up the arguments are never send across the network.